# How to accept both dot and comma as a decimal separator with WTForms?

Tags: python, decimal, wtforms

I'm using [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/) to display and validate form input.  I use a [`DecimalField`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.DecimalField) for a money amount input, which works fine when inserting a value with a dot as a decimal separator.  Since this website will be used in continental Europe however, I *also* want to allow a comma as a decimal separator. This means that *both* "2.5" and "2,5" should result in a value meaning "two and a half".

When I input a value with a comma, I get an error saying `'Not a valid decimal value'`.  How can I accept both dots and commas as decimal separators with WTForms?

---

I know I can use Babel to use locale-based number formatting, but I don't want that. I specifically want to accept both a dot and a comma as separator values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can subclass `DecimalField` and replace commas with periods before the data is processed:

```
class FlexibleDecimalField(fields.DecimalField):

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            valuelist[0] = valuelist[0].replace(",", ".")
        return super(FlexibleDecimalField, self).process_formdata(valuelist)
```

Comment: And what would it be for overriding the DecimalField model, in models.py?

Answer (score 0):

```
class FlexibleDecimalField(forms.DecimalField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        # check decimal symbol
        comma_index = 0
        dot_index = 0
        try:
            comma_index = value.index(',')
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            dot_index = value.index('.')
        except ValueError:
            pass
        if value:
            if comma_index > dot_index:
                value = value.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')
        return super(FlexibleDecimalField, self).to_python(value)

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    discount_value = FlexibleDecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('discount_value',)
```